# Fill in missing boolean rows in Pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have a MySQL query that is doing a groupby and returning data in the following form:

> ID | Boolean | Count

Sometimes there isn't data in the table for one of the boolean states, so data for a single ID might be returned like this:

> 1234 | 0 | 10

However I need it in this form for downstream analysis:

> 1234 | 0 | 10
>   1234 | 1 | 0

with an index on [ID, Boolean].

From querying Google and SO, it seems like getting MySQL to do this transform is a bit of a pain. Is there a simple way to do this in Pandas? I haven't been able to find anything useful in the docs or the Pandas cookbook.

You can assume that I've already loaded the data into a Pandas dataframe with no indexes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set the index of your dataframe to the `ID` and `Boolean` columns, and the construct an new index from the Cartesian product of the unique values.

That would look like this:

```
import pandas
indexcols = ['ID', 'Boolean']

data = pandas.read_sql_query(engine, querytext)
full_index = pandas.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [data['ID'].unique(), [0, 1]], 
    names=indexcols
)

data = (
    data.set_index(indexcols)
        .reindex(full_index)
        .fillna(0)
        .reset_index()
)
```